# Convert numeral date(03-11-1991) into arabic no(۱۹۹۱/۱۱/۰۳) php

Tags: php, string, arabic

I just want to convert the date which is in this format dd-mm-yyyy(03-11-1991) into arabic no like this(۱۹۹۱/۱۱/۰۳) in php.

**Answer**
I Made This Logic And It Works Perfect

```
   $dateofbirth_numerial="03-05-2001";
                             $numerial_no = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","-");
                             $arabic_no = array("۰","۱","۲","۳","۴","۵","۶","۷","۸","۹","/");
                             $dateofbirth_arabic = str_replace($numerial_no , $arabic_no , $dateofbirth_numerial);
                             $result = explode('/',$dateofbirth_arabic);
                             echo $result[2]."/".$result[1]."/".$result[0]; /* yyyy/mm/dd */
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert English numbers to Arabic numerals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386835/convert-english-numbers-to-arabic-numerals)

Comment: Good but I would say that's not a proper way of doing it. Anyway Alhamdulillah!

Comment: JAZAKALLAH.Yes Brother You Were Right I Changed The Logic Again Because on previous one because of doing reverse string..
"03-11-2001"
۱۰۰۲/۱۱/۳۰//wrong
but Know This Logic Is Working Perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP Localization approach:

```
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ar');
    $arabic = strftime('%A %e %B %Y', time());
    echo $arabic;
```

In case you didn't see Arabic letters rather Latin, this could be because the locale is not installed on your system. You can check the installed locales by running the command: `locale -a`

Please refer to the documentation for more options: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$standard = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$eastern_arabic_symbols = array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩");
$current_date = date('d').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('Y');
$arabic_date = str_replace($standard , $eastern_arabic_symbols , $current_date);
```

you can try `str_replace` function