# Display date also in Arabic numbers - PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert numeral date(03-11-1991) into arabic no(۱۹۹۱/۱۱/۰۳) php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646546/convert-numeral-date03-11-1991-into-arabic-no-php)

This is my client's requirement. He want to show Today's date in Normal numbers and below that in Arabic numbers too. [see this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWnOS.png)

I can get the current date easily by the following code snippet :

```
$current_date = date('d').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('Y');
```

but how could i convert the numbers to Arabic numbers and display them.?
Please advice good methods to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this [uk.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) or you can use the below string replace function

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$standard = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$eastern_arabic_symbols = array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩");
$current_date = date('d').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('Y');
$arabic_date = str_replace($standard , $eastern_arabic_symbols , $current_date);
```

Comment: I will up your answer if you give a example with intlDateFormatter

Comment: @artragis, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1419021/1343222 sorry i dont have enough time to try this.. :(

Comment: Those arabic numbers seem to be reversed regarding to western numbers...

Comment: Thanks. str_replace did the job :)

Comment: @jackflash, strrev will help?

Comment: Nope. I meant the translation won't be right because `$eastern_arabic_symbols` are inversely ordered. But I just realize that they are just *shown* in inversed order (due to RTL arabic writing I guess). It's OK. Thanks @LoverOfEvening!