# convert Persian/Arabic numbers to English numbers

Tags: php, unicode

How can I convert **Persian/Arabic numbers** to **English numbers** with a simple function ?

***Persian/Arabic numbers:***

```
۰   //  -> 0
۱   //  -> 1
۲   //  -> 2
۳   //  -> 3
۴   //  -> 4
۵   //  -> 5
۶   //  -> 6
۷   //  -> 7
۸   //  -> 8
۹   //  -> 9
```

numbers over the unicode :

```
$num0="&#1776;";
$num1="&#1777;";
$num2="&#1778;";
$num3="&#1779;";
$num4="&#1780;";
$num5="&#1781;";
$num6="&#1782;";
$num7="&#1783;";
$num8="&#1784;";
$num9="&#1785;";
```

Comment: Use google translate...just kidding :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386835/convert-english-numbers-to-arabic-numerals

Comment: Well, you can always use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu , Thanks friends .. First post edited , I add my function was created by me , but don't work ! anyone know ?

Comment: @Palladium Can you check function created by me ? that's added to first post .

Comment: I can do you one better. See answer.

Comment: those are actually Indian numbers to Arabic.
not Arabic to english

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Because people in the Persian & Arabic region maybe use each other keyboard types, this is the complete solution to convert both types.

Based on @palladium answer.

```
function convert2english($string) {
    $newNumbers = range(0, 9);
    // 1. Persian HTML decimal
    $persianDecimal = array('&#1776;', '&#1777;', '&#1778;', '&#1779;', '&#1780;', '&#1781;', '&#1782;', '&#1783;', '&#1784;', '&#1785;');
    // 2. Arabic HTML decimal
    $arabicDecimal = array('&#1632;', '&#1633;', '&#1634;', '&#1635;', '&#1636;', '&#1637;', '&#1638;', '&#1639;', '&#1640;', '&#1641;');
    // 3. Arabic Numeric
    $arabic = array('٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩');
    // 4. Persian Numeric
    $persian = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');

    $string =  str_replace($persianDecimal, $newNumbers, $string);
    $string =  str_replace($arabicDecimal, $newNumbers, $string);
    $string =  str_replace($arabic, $newNumbers, $string);
    return str_replace($persian, $newNumbers, $string);
}
```

Comment: This is based by @palladium answer .

Comment: Note : in number number 3 of this answer (Arabic Numbers) , they are in correct direction, just shown on wrong direction here.

Answer (score 111):

Here's a short function:

```
function convert($string) {
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $arabic = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨', '٩'];

    $num = range(0, 9);
    $convertedPersianNums = str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($arabic, $num, $convertedPersianNums);
    
    return $englishNumbersOnly;
}
```

You can use the unicode instead of the characters in `$persian` (I think).

Comment: When you copy and paste this code, arabic order will be reversed, be careful!

Comment: How to pass my page body from this function?

Comment: To avoid having the Arabic numbers' order reversed:

$arabic = ['٠', '١', '٢', '٣', '٤', '٥', '٦', '٧', '٨','٩'];

Answer (score 41):

I use this function. It converts both Persian and Arabic digits to English:

```
function faTOen($string) {
    return strtr($string, array('۰'=>'0', '۱'=>'1', '۲'=>'2', '۳'=>'3', '۴'=>'4', '۵'=>'5', '۶'=>'6', '۷'=>'7', '۸'=>'8', '۹'=>'9', '٠'=>'0', '١'=>'1', '٢'=>'2', '٣'=>'3', '٤'=>'4', '٥'=>'5', '٦'=>'6', '٧'=>'7', '٨'=>'8', '٩'=>'9'));
}
```

sample:

```
echo faTOen("۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"); // 01234567890123456789
```

Also you can convert English to Persian the same way:

```
function enToFa($string) {
    return strtr($string, array('0'=>'۰','1'=>'۱','2'=>'۲','3'=>'۳','4'=>'۴','5'=>'۵','6'=>'۶','7'=>'۷','8'=>'۸','9'=>'۹'));
}
```

Or English to Arabic:

```
function enToAr($string) {
    return strtr($string, array('0'=>'٠','1'=>'١','2'=>'٢','3'=>'٣','4'=>'٤','5'=>'٥','6'=>'٦','7'=>'٧','8'=>'٨','9'=>'٩'));
}
```

Comment: The fastest answer about performance.

Answer (score 13):

this is better.
we have two type of digits in arabic and persian. we must change all.

```
function convert($string) {
    $persinaDigits1= array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
    $persinaDigits2= array('٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١', '٠');
    $allPersianDigits=array_merge($persinaDigits1, $persinaDigits2);
    $replaces = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
    return str_replace($allPersianDigits, $replaces , $string);
}
```

*thanks @Palladium*

Be Careful when copying the code! Check twice how the array is presented in your editor or your will be in trouble!

Comment: Thanks @iman , but on above codes , sort of persian and English numbers not true. but Thanks for notify . (Mamnoon)

Comment: hi @root. i used correct code with correct order (i copied it from correct code) but text editor of stack overflow changed it's order and i could not correct it!

Comment: Thanks for two type of digits (arabic and persian)

Comment: Unfortunately this returns 899 for number `١٠٠`!

Answer (score 8):

```
$fmt = numfmt_create('fa', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo numfmt_parse($fmt, "۵") . "\n";
// 5
```

Comment: Have Error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function numfmt_create()`

Comment: Did you forget to install the intl extension, like the docs say?

Comment: $formatter = \NumberFormatter::create('en', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL); echo $formatter->parse('۵');

Answer (score 5):

For convert all persian number to english format you can use this function:

```
function Convertnumber2english($srting) {

        $srting = str_replace('۰', '0', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۱', '1', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۲', '2', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۳', '3', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۴', '4', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۵', '5', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۶', '6', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۷', '7', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۸', '8', $srting);
        $srting = str_replace('۹', '9', $srting);

        return $srting;
    }
```

Comment: Mamnoon , Vali HamunTour ke dar bala eshare kardam , donbale Raveshi budam ke dar Kootahtarin zaman Execute in kar ro anjam bede (say at Phinglish , Persian as English characters)

Comment: on this way , you using nine time of str_replace function . believe shortest way ?

Answer (score 4):

**Two useful functions:**

First convert to English number:

```
function convert_to_en_number($string) {
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $arabic = ['٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١','٠'];

    $num = range(0, 9);
    $convertedPersianNums = str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
    $englishNumbersOnly = str_replace($arabic, $num, $convertedPersianNums);

    return $englishNumbersOnly;
}
```

Second convert to Persian number:

```
function convert_to_fa_number($string) {
    $num = range(0, 9);
    $arabic = ['٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١','٠'];
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];

    $convertedEnglishNums = str_replace($num, $persian, $string);
    $persianNumbersOnly = str_replace($arabic, $persian, $convertedEnglishNums);

    return $persianNumbersOnly;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Very easy way to convert **Arabic numbers to English number** digits using below function:

```
function ArtoEnNumeric($string) {
    return strtr($string, array('۰'=>'0', '۱'=>'1', '۲'=>'2', '۳'=>'3', '۴'=>'4', '۵'=>'5', '۶'=>'6', '۷'=>'7', '۸'=>'8', '۹'=>'9', '٠'=>'0', '١'=>'1', '٢'=>'2', '٣'=>'3', '٤'=>'4', '٥'=>'5', '٦'=>'6', '٧'=>'7', '٨'=>'8', '٩'=>'9'));
}

echo ArtoEnNumeric('۶۰۶۳١۶۳٨'); 
Output = 60631638
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a six-year old question, but I just came across this and developed a generic solution and I'd like to share it here for future readers.

Basically I use the [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) to generate the numbers in any foreign language, then I replace the numbers in the input string with the ones from English.

It should work for any language, but I wrote mine for Arabic.

```
/**
 * Replace Arabic numbers by English numbers in a string
 *
 * @param $value string A string containing Arabic numbers.
 * @param $source_language string The locale to convert chars from.
 *
 * @return string The string with Arabic numbers replaced by English numbers
 */
function englishifyNumbers ($value, $source_language = 'ar') {
    // Remove any direction overriding chars [LRO (U+202D)]
    $value = trim($value);

    // Create an Arabic number formatter to generate Arabic numbers
    $fmt = new \NumberFormatter(
        $source_language, 
        \NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL
    );

    // Create an array of English numbers to use for replacement
    $english_numbers = range(0, 9);

    // Convert the English numbers to Arabic numbers using the formatter
    $arabic_numbers = array_map(function ($n) use ($fmt) {
        // Trim to remove direction overriding chars [PDF (U+202C)]
        return trim($fmt->format($n));

    }, $english_numbers);

    // Replace the numbers and return the result
    return str_replace($arabic_numbers, $english_numbers, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sting= '٩٨٥٤٠٣٧٦٣٢١'; 

// search stings
$seachstrings = array("١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩", "٠"); 

// replace strings 
$replacestrings= array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"); 

// replace function 
$result= str_replace($seachstrings , $replacestrings, $sting); 

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better answer using some kind of replace, but for coding it yourself, this would be better than what you have:

```
$len = strlen($arabic);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i )
{
    switch( $arabic[$i] )
    {
    case '&#1776':
        $english .= '0';
        break;
    case '&#1777':
        $english .= '1';
        break;
    case '&#1778':
        $english .= '2';
        break;
    // and so on
    case '&#1785':
        $english .= '9';
        break;
    default:
        $english .= $arabic[$i];
    }
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this...

```
$number = arbic_to_english("&#1777;&#1779;");

echo $number; // 13

function arbic_to_english($number) {
    $english_number = 0;
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/&#\d{4};/', $number, $matches);
    if(!count($matches) || !count($matches[0])) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid number');
    }
    $power = count($matches[0]) - 1;
    foreach($matches[0] as $arbic_digit) {
        $english_digit = preg_replace('/&#\d{2}(\d{2});/', '$1', $arbic_digit) - 76;
        $english_number += $english_digit * pow(10, $power--);
    }
    return $english_number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , input numbers must be in range of this numbers : `۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` , Now i test it , but don't work

Answer (score 0):

No need to divide the input string.

```
private function convert($input)
{
    $unicode = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '٤', '٥', '٦', '۷', '۸', '۹');
    $english = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');

    $string = str_replace($unicode, $english , $input);

    return $string;
}
```

Examples

```
convert("۱۲۳٤٥");   //output : 12345

convert("۱۲34٥");   //output : 12345

convert("12345");   //output : 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php):

```
$formatter = \NumberFormatter::create('en', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo $formatter->parse('۱۳۹۹'); // outputs: 1399
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that takes a string and zero of source language and zero of destination language

In below example I am converting numbers from Hindi to Latin for a given string

```js
val = LangNum2Num("जिनसे आप कुछ ९० सीख सकते ३४ हैं हम लाये हैं ७ आपके लिये कुछ", "०", 0)
console.log(val)
// Prints जिनसे आप कुछ 90 सीख सकते 34 हैं हम लाये हैं 7 आपके लिये कुछ




// Coverts numbers insides a string to other language number
// str is the string
// zeroFrom is the zero number from the language you want to convert
// zeroTo is the zero number of the languague you want to convert to

function LangNum2Num(str, zeroFrom, zeroTo) {
  // Get the UTF-16 code points of zeros
  codezeroFrom = ("" + zeroFrom).codePointAt(0)
  codezeroTo = ("" + zeroTo).codePointAt(0)

  // Make array containing codepoints from 0 to 10 for the language
  var FromArr = [...Array(10).keys()].map(e => codezeroFrom + e)
  var ToArr = [...Array(10).keys()].map(e => codezeroTo + e)

  // Split the string into array, if we catch a number, we will return number from destination language
  return str.split('').map(e => FromArr.includes(e.codePointAt(0)) ? String.fromCodePoint(ToArr[FromArr.indexOf(e.codePointAt(0))]) : e).join('')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this function

```php
function toEngNumbers($string)
{
    $arabic = ['٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١', '٠'];
    $persian = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
    $english = ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'];

    $convertedPersianNums = str_replace($persian, $english, $string);
    $converted = str_replace($arabic, $english, $convertedPersianNums);
    return $converted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Root answer:

```
function to_english_number( $string ) {

    $persianDecimal = [ '&#1776;', '&#1777;', '&#1778;', '&#1779;', '&#1780;', '&#1781;', '&#1782;', '&#1783;', '&#1784;', '&#1785;' ];
    $arabicDecimal  = [ '&#1632;', '&#1633;', '&#1634;', '&#1635;', '&#1636;', '&#1637;', '&#1638;', '&#1639;', '&#1640;', '&#1641;' ];

    $persian = [ '۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹' ];
    $arabic  = [ '٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١', '٠' ];

    $num = range( 0, 9 );

    $string = str_replace( $persianDecimal, $num, $string );
    $string = str_replace( $arabicDecimal, $num, $string );

    $string = str_replace( $persian, $num, $string );
    $string = str_replace( $arabic, $num, $string );

    return $string;
}
```