# Is it possible to compare unicode numbers with mysql int columns?

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization

I have a table with an integer value. In my application there is a text field that user enters his desired number to search. If user enter number in English there is no problem. but if his keyboard is not english and enters a number that exists in table mysql doesn't find it. ***I can't change application to convert user input to english numbers***. Is there a way to solve this problem in mysql(config, table structure,etc.)?

for example I have this record in database:

`Order_number = 112, ...`

If user search for 112 in english, mysql returns the above row. but if user enters 112 for example in persian(۱۱۲) mysql returns an empty set.

Comment: give examples to improve clarity

Comment: @rambocoder added an example

Comment: you have to "translate" that in your app

Comment: @SirRufo I can't change the application

Comment: [This post has info about that conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-arabic-persian-numbers-to-english-numbers)

Comment: How many different forms can the numbers take on? If its not too many, and one to one mappings exist to the english style numbers, you might be able to just use a bunch of REPLACE() calls.

Comment: Numbers (e.g. INT values) in MySQL has to be addressed with digits 0..9 as designed. All other will be interpreted as chars. IMHO no way without app modification

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(112 AS CHAR) = '۱۱۲' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(112 AS CHAR) = '۱۱۲' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    1 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Worst case, you could do something like

```
... where 112 = replace('۱', 1, replace('۲', 2, 'user input here'));
```

I assume all inputs have 10 distinct digits in their number representations, just that they use different characters to represent the digits.

Comment: [I hope you're not serious about this...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit#Numerals_in_most_popular_systems)