# i want to convert arebic numbers to english and i tried code below

Tags: php

```
$persian = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
$num = range(0, 9);
echo  str_replace($persian,  $num,'٢٢٢');
```

I am getting same arebic numbers in result. it is not converting to english numbers.

Comment: you can check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with below code:-

```
<?php

function str_split_unicode($str, $length = 1) {
    $tmp = preg_split('~~u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ($length > 1) {
        $chunks = array_chunk($tmp, $length);
        foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {
            $chunks[$i] = join('', (array) $chunk);
        }
        $tmp = $chunks;
    }
    return $tmp;
}

function convert($string) {
    $data = '';
    $persian = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
    $num = range(0, 9);
    foreach($string as $new_str){
        $data .= str_replace($persian, $num, $new_str);
    }
    return $data;
}
$data = str_split_unicode('۰۲۳'); // convert number into single dimensional array

echo $new_data = convert($data); // pass that array to convert function and then concatenate the whole data to get final English number
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/527884

Reference taken from here and modified :- [convert Persian/Arabic numbers to English numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers)

Comment: it doesn't convert more then one numbers. if i pass '.٢٢'  in string i am getting '0٢٢' in result

Comment: what is the solution if i have to convert a whole string to english

Comment: ٩٩ add this in $data = str_split_unicode('٩٩'); doesn't work

Comment: Its working for me. Actually the format you provided is not correct ,i just copy paste '۹۹' from the `$persian` array and it worked. check. see this :- https://eval.in/527911