# MySQL Converting string Indian numbers to standard integer

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I have prices stored as varchar written in [Indian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system), e.g. `'١٨٠٠'`.
Is there a way to convert these data to standard integers e.g. `1800`?

input table

```
|price|
|١٨٠٠ |
|200  |
```

output table

```
|price|
|1800 |
|200  |
```

I tried FOMAT() with en_US locale but it returns zero

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, why are numbers stored as strings and not as, well, numbers?

Comment: I did, bad design from prev jr developer

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you want to achieve? If these are usual strings, it should not be too hard to convert them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert Persian/Arabic numbers to English numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers)

Comment: NO I need mysql not php, I tried FOMAT() with en_US locale but it returns zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is clear indian number, without additional symbols, then use

```
SELECT UNHEX(REPLACE(HEX(indian_value), @prefix, '3')) AS arabic_value
```

For the symbols in your sample data `@prefix = 'D9A'`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abb67d7ac6a8b3e476269d347b1b08ec)